# what does React setState() return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `this.setState()`inside of a ternary and trying to figure out what it returns. The documentation doesn't provide any information as to what it returns.

Comment: I dont think it returns anything. Its a setter

Comment: Are you trying to read back what was set in state and take a decision based on it? If yes, you should move that logic in a callback function and send it as the second parameter to `setState`. The `setState` function schedules an update and the state is neither immediately modified, nor is it returned from the call as value. The right way to take action _after_ the state has been updated is through a callback as the second parameter.

Answer (score 13):

As commented before,

> I dont think it returns anything. Its a setter.

You can refer [setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to understand what it does.

Now to answer your question, since react is closely associated with Typescript, following code is from the `index.d.ts` file of react. You can find the file [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) and you can check the definition [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L284)

```js
setState<K extends keyof S>(f: (prevState: Readonly<S>, props: P) => Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
```

As you see, both the definitions have same return type: `void`. This is because, first, it is a setter function. Second, on most occasion, setState will trigger a re-render. So you will not be able to do much.

If you have to do some processing after setState, you can pass a callback as second argument.

Comment: According to the type definition, `setState` returns `void`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4d94351d9032d2c6d2cc76b0e80c42529fda3157/types/react/index.d.ts#L485-L488

Comment: That is what the answer says. Correct? Its a setter function. It takes a value and sets it. There is no need to return anything

Comment: It's important to mention that you can't pass a callback as a second argument if you're using the hook version, like useState() and useReducer(). Any processing after the state change should be put on an useEffect() call.

Comment: @timarcosdias Though you are correct, but the post is about `setState`. With hooks, its altogether a different story

Answer (score 2):

React's `setState()` function that lacks an explicit return statement and thus will return `undefined`. If you require a return value from `setState()`, you should use the `!!` which will coerce it to return `false`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

setState() returns undefined,
but if you would like to 'hack' it and return true

just use:

```
!!!setState({...}) //returns true
```