# javascript conditional with ampersand statements only reading first half

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having trouble with the conditional statement, currently if `selectedItem = null` it will set `setOption = dropdownItems[0].value` but wont set `setPage = 1` and same with the line below it, any feedback on whats going on?

> This is my current code

```
      <button {...getToggleButtonProps()}>
              {selectedItem === null 
                ? setOption(dropdownItems[0].value) && setPage(1)
                : setOption(selectedItem.value) && setPage(1) }
              {`${option}`}
          <ArrowIcon isOpen={isOpen} />
       </button>
```

Comment: What does `setOption()` return? If it returns undefined or a falsy value, the rest of the statement will short circuit.

Comment: Is there any reason `setOption` is executed per render and not on some event like, say, click on the button, by the way?

Comment: setOption changes when a user switches between the different dropdown options for which database to search in, when a new database is chosen i also want to reset page number to 1 @Fleischpflanzerl

Comment: @MarkMeyer it returns a string 'Database A' for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `&&` to execute both expressions, the first one has to return a truthy value, otherwise the right hand side will not be executed:

```js
const returnsFalse = () => false;
const returnsTrue = () => true;
const returnsNothing = () => {};

returnsFalse() && console.log("does not work with false");
returnsTrue() && console.log("works with true");
returnsNothing() && console.log("does not work with no return value");
```

The `setOption` [function does not return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545708/what-does-react-setstate-return)

You can use the comma operator if you want both expressions executed without relying on their return values:

```js
const returnsFalse = () => false;
const returnsTrue = () => true;
const returnsNothing = () => {};

(returnsFalse(), console.log("works with false"));
(returnsTrue(), console.log("works with true"));
(returnsNothing(), console.log("works with no return value"));
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
<button {...getToggleButtonProps()}>
      {selectedItem === null 
        ? setOption(dropdownItems[0].value), setPage(1)
        : setOption(selectedItem.value), setPage(1) }
      {`${option}`}
  <ArrowIcon isOpen={isOpen} />
</button>
```

An alternative, if you want call `setPage` after `setOption` is complete, would be to utilise [the callback parameter](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and pass a function that will call `setPage(1)` to `setOption`:

```
<button {...getToggleButtonProps()}>
      {selectedItem === null 
        ? setOption(dropdownItems[0].value, () => setPage(1))
        : setOption(selectedItem.value, () => setPage(1)) }
      {`${option}`}
  <ArrowIcon isOpen={isOpen} />
</button>
```

Comment: this is very helpful, however setOption returns a string. This is how I have it initialized  `const [option, setOption] = React.useState('All');` and then based on what the user chooses I want to set it to 'Database A' or 'Database B' and so on

Comment: @CatGirl19 [it seems like it doesn't return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545708/what-does-react-setstate-return). It will set the value only.