# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when I try to use items.map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render cards with data from db. When I run the code I get the error "Cannot read property "map" of undefined". Any ideas? What am I doing wrong

```
const ProductList =  () =>
 {
  const [prodList, setProdList] = useState();
  const [ pass, setPass] = useState();
    const getitems = async () => {await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/services').then((response) => setPass(response.data));}

  useEffect(() => {
    getitems().then((pass) => setProdList(pass));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
   
      <Container maxWidth={false}>
        <ProductListToolbar />
        <Box sx={{ pt: 3 }}>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={3}
          >
            {prodList.map((product) => (
              <Grid
                item
                key={product.serviceID}
                lg={4}
                md={6}
                xs={12}
              >
                <ProductCard product={product} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>)}

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: pass initial value as `[]` for your state . `const [prodList, setProdList] = useState([]);`

Comment: Also here is the Productcard component:  https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-rgb-occ48?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Shyam I get the same error. Plus it says that " (anonymous function) > 21 |   getitems().then((pass) => setProdList(pass)); "

Comment: Have added my answer ! Please take a look .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to make few changes in your code,

1. Always pass an initial value to the state , else it will be undefined.
2. We dont need the state `pass`, we are not using it anywhere in the code .
3. We should not mix async/await with the then/catch . We should use either of them and not both.
4. When making API calls it is a good practice to have the loading state , so that we can show some meaningful message to the user until we fetch the data .

With the above changes, we can refactor your code as

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const [prodList, setProdList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const getItems = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/services');

      setProdList(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <p> Fetching the Products ... </p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth={false}>
        <ProductListToolbar />
        <Box sx={{pt: 3}}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {prodList.map((product) => (
              <Grid item key={product.serviceID} lg={4} md={6} xs={12}>
                <ProductCard product={product} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Shyam already suggested very good recommendations to your codebase. I will attempt to explain why your previous way did not work instead.

This is highly likely because of your `getitems` function (a small note: I try to aim for consistent case in naming things, so I recommend you change the function name to `getItems`). In short, your `getItems` function does not return a promise with **data**.

JS Promise works like a chain. If the previous "node" returns something, the later "node" will receive that data as a parameter

However, the last action in the promise chain of `getItems` was `.then(response => setPass(response.data)`; but the `setPass` function [returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545708/what-does-react-setstate-return)  --> `getItems` returns `Promise<undefined>`

Therefore: When you use `getItems.then(pass => setProdList(pass))` (in your `useEffect`)

--> `Promise<undefined>.then(pass => setProdlist(pass))`

--> `pass` received the `undefined` value

--> `setProdList(undefined)`

--> cannot read `map` of `undefined`

I hope these steps above help illustrate how data is passed in the promise chain. JS Promise is not some kind of magic - you need to be careful of what you return in your promise chain.

The solution to the problem is a bit refactoring of your code. There is some not-so-good design decisions on your part:

- You are not having initial states in your `useState`
- You are mixing async/await with `then`
- You are calling `setState` both inside (with `setPass`) and outside (with `setProdList`) the `getItems` function. It is a bit inconsistent IMO, and make it harder to debug. Either both inside, or both outside.

Therefore, I suggest simply putting the `.then` calls outside the `getItems` function. Let `getItems` have a single responsibility of making the Axios call, and whatever we want to do with the response, we put it in the `useEffect`. And also use some initial state for your `useState`

```js
const [prodList, setProdList] = useState([]);
const [pass, setPass] = useState([]);
const getItems = async () => {
  await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/services");
};

useEffect(() => {
  getItems().then((response) => {
    const pass = response.data;
    // Use both `setState` here, no need to separate them
    setPass(pass);
    setProdList(pass);
  });
}, []);
```

Hope this helped.